# Laravel returns old model after update

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When i store a new record, Laravel returns the new record. Everything works fine.
When i update a record, Laravel returns the old record. I like to return the updated record.

Controller

```
    public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $this->repo->create( $request->all());

        return response()->json(new ProjectResource($data));
    }

    public function update(UpdateProjectRequest $request, Project $project)
    {
        $data = $this->repo->update($project, $request->all());

        return response()->json(new ProjectResource($data));
    }
```

Repository

```
    public function create( $data)
    {
        $this->model->name = $data['name'];
        $this->model->description = $data['description'];
        $this->model->sales_order_id = $data['sales_order_id'] ? $data['sales_order_id'] : NULL;
        $this->model->project_leader_id = $data['project_leader_id'];
        $this->model->project_type_id = $data['project_type_id'];
        $this->model->project_status_id = $data['project_status_id'];
        $this->model->creator_id = Auth()->id();
        $this->model->save();

        return $this->model;
    }

    public function update($model, $data)
    {
        $model->name = $data['name'];
        $model->description = $data['description'];
        $model->sales_order_id = $data['sales_order_id'];
        $model->project_leader_id = $data['project_leader_id'];
        $model->project_type_id = $data['project_type_id'];
        $model->project_status_id = $data['project_status_id'];
        $model->save();

        return $model;
    }
```

When i add `$data = Project::find($project->id)`i receive the updated model.

But is this the only way?

Comment: that is the model with the updated attributes you are directly setting, what are you expecting to happen besides it having new values for the attributes you are setting?

Comment: The return of the repo update is the model with old values. With ‘$data->fresh()‘ the return is with updated values. I found it out with google but i still not understand, why the first version doesn‘t return the updated model

Comment: it is returning the model with the new values you directly assign to it unless you have some mutators that are doing something odd

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason the `$data` is returning as the old data is because it still stores the data from when the variable was created. When you call `$data->fresh()` it will go fetch the new data and return it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an instance of an Eloquent model that was retrieved from the database, you can "refresh" the model using the fresh and refresh methods

[Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#refreshing-models)

fresh method will re-retrieve the model from the database. The existing model instance will not be affected

The refresh method will re-hydrate the existing model using fresh data from the database. In addition, all of its loaded relationships will be refreshed as well